# Unable to resolve following error using Django tutorial - ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: django, syncdb

I'm using the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) for learning how to use Django.

I'm unable to resolve this error

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

This error comes up after I type

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

The django version being used is 1.5 on CentOS

Comment: Could you paste your settings.py, please?

Comment: So, have you supplied the ENGINE value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify [ENGINE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#engine) value in [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#databases) setting in your `settings.py`. The available options are

- `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`
- `django.db.backends.mysql`
- `django.db.backends.sqlite3`
- `django.db.backends.oracle`

You can also specify a custom backend. Refer [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#engine) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to specify your engine name if using postgresql or sqlite or mysql backends.

```
it's up to what kind of database you are using.
for example for postgresql:

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2',      
     }
```